# formatting text in a csv export

Tags: filemaker

I'm having trouble with a .csv export which is being uploaded to a website. There are must be some hidden or illegal characters in a description field I have in the database. I'm having a tough time getting the text to format correctly and not break a php script.

If I use the GetAs(css) function in a calculation, the text works fine. Obviously this won't work as a working file but it at least validates there's something in the formatting of the description field that's breaking the export. I did use the excel clean(text) calculation and that fixes the issue as well. Just need to find a way in Filemaker to do this.

Any suggestions?? Maybe a custom function that strips out bad characters?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter invalid characters out of text using the [filter](http://www.filemaker.com/help/html/func_ref3.33.48.html) function. If you only want a minimal set of ASCII characters, use it like

```
filter(mytable::myfield; "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0123456789.!?")
```

Comment: Although PHP is probably breaking because of UTF-16 unicode characters in the file. You can try decoding these using http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php